# Elasticsearch with geo location

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, geospatial

Little Background.

Our software uses MongoDB to save data. We have created text index and geo location index on it. Problem is query using both text and goe location is not supported in MongoDB.

Our requirement is to search using natural language, restricting search to particular geo location and sorting result by geo location distance.

Question:
We are thinking to use elasticsearch for this purpose. Does elastic search supports above specified requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html#_lat_lon_as_array_4) one example of a geo filter with a match_all query. And [here's](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/sorting-by-distance.html) another example with sorting.